# Crate an object with unique key in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create an object with unique key like:

```js
let id = Symbol("id");
let id2 = Symbol("id");

const obj = {
      [id]: ()=>  'test'
}


console.log(obj[id]())
```

In the case above, i can access the return value only if i have the `Symbol`. And this works.
Question: How to create a condition to avoid the error `id is not defined` if i do this:

```js
//let id = Symbol("id");
//let id2 = Symbol("id");

const obj = {
      [id]: ()=>  'test'
}


console.log(obj[id]())
```

So in this case i don't want to get an error but just to get the empty object or something like this. How to handle this?

Comment: Why not just do something like `if (typeof id !== "undefined)"`? And in general, why *would* you try to use a variable that might or might not be declared?

Answer (score 1):

you can check the property existence in that object before calling it, refer [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```js
    let id = Symbol("id");
    let id2 = Symbol("id");

    const obj = {
          [id]: ()=>  'test'
    }

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(id2)) { // false 
      console.log(obj[id2]());
    }
    
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(id)) { // true
      console.log(obj[id]()); 
    }
```

id2 won't be printed because that property not exist in the object but id does

Comment: Assuming OP doesn't even have the variable `id` declared (I still don't know why) then `hasOwnProperty` doesn't help since it still reads the missing variable and would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-catch block.

```
try {
    const obj = {
      [id]: ()=>  'test'
    }
} catch(err) { console.log('test error catched. Do what you want to do here.'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to check for undeclared variable errors or so, this is just crapy.

If your goal is just to build an object with some method, built it just simply as:

```
const test = () => 'test';

const obj1 = { somethingYouWant: test };
const obj2 = { id: test };
const obj3 = { otherThing: test };
```